# Spring Security in Grails redirects to HTTP login page

Tags: tomcat, grails, nginx, https

I am running a Grails 2.5.5 app in a Tomcat behind a nginx proxy (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

The nginx has both HTTP and HTTPS configured but redirects everything to HTTPS and sends Strict-Transport-Security header.

I have the problem that even when I call my app via HTTPS via

https://example.com/someurl

I get a redirect from the Grails app to the login page as HTTP:

http://example.com/login/auth

I tried to configure grails.serverURL but that did not make any difference.

Why does Grails/Spring Security not stay on HTTPS or not recognise that I am already calling the App via HTTPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem and I was able to solve it by configuring the `org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve` in the tomcat `server.xml`:

```xml
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
               internalProxies="172\.18\..*"
               remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
               protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

This way tomcat detects correctly what the remote IP is, what scheme is used and if the request is secure.